# Con quali altre parole puoi dire "cuore a cuore" in questo contesto (canzone)?

Tags: meaning

**It. attuale**

```
Com'è bello far l'amore quando è sera,
cuore a cuore con una bimba che è sincera.
Quelle stelle che ci guardano lassù
non sono belle come gli occhi che hai tu.
Luce bianca, dormiveglia di un lampione,
che ti mostra dove tu puoi baciarti,
specialmente tra le rose a primavera,
com'è bello far l'amore quando è sera.
```

**Original**

```
Com'è bello fa' l'amore quanno è sera,
core a core co' 'na pupa ch'è sincera.
Quelle stelle che ce guardeno lassù
nun so' belle come l'occhi che ciai tu.
Luce bianca, dormiveja d'un lampione,
che t'insegna dove tu te poi bacià,
speciarmente tra le rose a primavera,
com'è bello fa' l'amore quanno è sera.
```

Comment: Puoi aggiungere qualcosa? Di che si tratta? Una poesia, una canzone, una cosa che ti ha detto qualcuno?

Comment: - DaG - Ho modificato la domanda, ma non credo che renda qualcosa di più semplice per rispondermi

Comment: eccolo qui - https://italiasempre.com/vedere/vedere_musica.php?ver=br&vedere=comebellofalam2

Comment: Il contesto è sempre indispensabile: l'italiano, come tutte le lingue, ha varianti nel tempo e nello spazio, ha diversi registri, da quelli colloquiali a quelli formali a quelli poetici etc. La stessa parola o espressione può avere significati diversissimi a seconda del contesto. Se tu non dai più dati, gli altri non possono rispondere oppure devono fare delle ricerche (come presumibilmente ha fatto Giuseppe) che tu avresti potuto risparmiare loro.

Comment: Vedo adesso dalle tue domande precedenti che sei interessato alle canzoni napoletane: comunicare all'interno di una domanda che si tratta di questo tipo di testi è già di grande aiuto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A core a core" è un'espressione regionale (dialetto napoletano e romano come nella canzone citata cantata da Claudio Villa) comunque utilizzata in altre parti d'Italia, senza essere tradotta "a cuore a cuore", che indica tenerezze tra innamorati, intimità, l'essere teneramente abbracciati.

È anche utilizzata in senso più ampio in espressioni tipo:

> Ti voglio dire una cosa a core a core.
> Vi voglio fare un discorso a core a core.

per indicare franchezza, sincerità, vicinanza emotiva; o alcune volte ironicamente in espressioni tipo:

> Guarda come si sono messi, a core a core.

a indicare il confabulare e il pettegolare di due persone.

Nel testo della canzone, "core a core" potrebbe essere sostituito con "teneramente abbracciato".

Comment: Adesso so tradurre in portoghese e spagnolo in modo che capiscano meglio cosa significa cuore a cuore  https://musicasitalianas.com/new/index.php?lang=br&canzone=comebellofalam2

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Ho citato tutti i possibili significati che conosco.

Comment: Un'altra possibile accezione potrebbe essere "stretto stretto" o "vicino vicino", come nella canzone "Quel che non si fa più" / "Les plaisirs démodés" (Charles Aznavour): «*Vieni e riscopri con me / Quel che non si fa più. / Stai guancia a guancia / E **cuore a cuore** sì, / E stringi più che puoi / Le braccia intorno a me. / Stai qui, contro di me, / Stai qui vicino a me.*»